# Alternative to adjustbox for table full page width

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I have a few multi column csv tables I am importing with \csvreader. Some are smaller than page width (Table 1), others are larger (Table 2). I would like to make them all exactly the full page width (6.5in). Adjustbox seems to scale the text size, spacing, line weight, etc, which I would like to maintain constant, and just stretch the table with added space in columns. I would prefer if in Table 2 text is wrapped if possible rather than using smaller font.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}               
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}   
\usepackage{fontspec}                   
\usepackage{tabularx}                   
\usepackage{longtable}                  
\usepackage{booktabs}                   
\usepackage{parskip}                    
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}              
\usepackage{sectsty}                    
\usepackage{titlesec}                   
\usepackage{float}                      
\usepackage[font=bf, skip=2pt]{caption}     
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage{csvsimple}                  
\usepackage{adjustbox}                  
\usepackage{datatool}                   
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}      
\newcommand\myhead[1]{\mbox{\centering\cellcolor{blue}\color{white}\bfseries #1}}   %Table header style         

%Table 1
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{file1.csv}
Timestamp, Fields, Issue
 xxx,111,222
 333,444,222
 xxx,111,222
 xxx,111,222
 \end{filecontents*}

%Table 2
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{file2.csv}
Timestamp, Fields, Issue
 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx,111111 11111 111111 1111111 1111 1111,222 2222222 22222 2222222 2222222
 333,444,222
 xxx,111,222
 xxx,111,222
 \end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

%Table 1
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:screening}Data Periods Removed during Data Quality Assessment}
\csvreader[head to column names, column count=3,respect all, tabular=l|c|c, 
table head=\myhead{Timestamp} & \myhead{Fields} & \myhead{Issue} \\\hline,
  late after first line=\\,
late after line=\\\hline,
  ]%
{file1.csv}{}{%  
\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
\end{table}

%Table 2
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:screening}Data Periods Removed during Data Quality Assessment}
\csvreader[head to column names, column count=3,respect all, tabular=l|c|c, 
table head=\myhead{Timestamp} & \myhead{Fields} & \myhead{Issue} \\\hline,
  late after first line=\\,
late after line=\\\hline,
  ]%
{file2.csv}{}{%  
\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii
}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Normally one uses `tabularx` for that purpose. Whether or not this works in your example, I do not know because your example is not a compilable document. Please make it compilable such that it starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hi thanks, Ok I just made compilable!

Comment: Thanks! It seems that tabularx is not supported. You could use for the second table something like `tabular=p{5cm}|>{\centering}p{4cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}`. Of course, you could compute the precise lengths that make it precisely fit by doing some algebra with `\tabcolsep` and friends. Please indicate if you need a precise fit.

Comment: Thank you!! This will work for now. I can probably figure out the math but for future, it would be nice if it did the math automatically somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: The idea is called `tabularx`. However, according to what I find it does not get directly supported in `cvsimple`. Of course, one could try to hack it.

Comment: Just to let you know that I think to know the reason why `tabularx` is not supported. This is one of those environments which need to see an explicit `\endtabularx` (or something like this) which makes it harder to build into other schemes.

Comment: Thanks yeah I tried to make tabularx work for ages without luck, and wasnt happy with adjustbox. This is a good solution for the meantime. The bit of algebra / guess and check, for each column width may not be a great long term solution tho. If you come across a more elegant solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be happy to remove this but you can just compute the distance.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}               
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}   
\usepackage{fontspec}                   
\usepackage{longtable}                  
\usepackage{booktabs}                   
\usepackage{parskip}                    
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}              
\usepackage[font=bf, skip=2pt]{caption}     
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage{csvsimple}                  
\usepackage{datatool}                   
\usepackage{pgf}                   
\newcommand\myhead[1]{\mbox{\centering\cellcolor{blue}\color{white}\bfseries #1}}   %Table header style         

%Table 1
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{file1.csv}
Timestamp, Fields, Issue
 xxx,111,222
 333,444,222
 xxx,111,222
 xxx,111,222
 \end{filecontents*}

%Table 2
\begin{filecontents*}{file2.csv}
Timestamp, Fields, Issue
 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx,111111 11111 111111 1111111 1111 1111,222 2222222 22222 2222222 2222222
 333,444,222
 xxx,111,222
 xxx,111,222
 \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

%Table 1
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:screening}Data Periods Removed during Data Quality Assessment}
\csvreader[head to column names, column count=3,respect all, tabular=l|c|c, 
table head=\myhead{Timestamp} & \myhead{Fields} & \myhead{Issue} \\\hline,
  late after first line=\\,
late after line=\\\hline,
  ]%
{file1.csv}{}{%  
\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
\end{table}

%Table 2
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{(\linewidth-6*\tabcolsep)/3}%
\caption{\label{tab:screening2}Data Periods Removed during Data Quality Assessment}
\csvreader[head to column names, column count=3,respect all, 
tabular=p{\mywidth pt}|>{\centering}p{\mywidth pt}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\mywidth pt}, 
table head=\myhead{Timestamp} & \myhead{Fields} & \myhead{Issue} \\\hline,
  late after first line=\\,
late after line=\\\hline,
  ]%
{file2.csv}{}{%  
\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`showframe` is only used to show that it works.